# Profile mobile Safari (iPad) javascript?

Tags: javascript, ipad, mobile-safari

Javascript performance on mobile Safari (iPad) is much more sensitive for my application that it is on the desktop. Some operations that work super-smooth on the desktop take a while on the iPad, and I'd like to track down where the bottlenecks are. Is there some way to profile Javascript code on the iPad?

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to an Android phone, you can profile your application using desktop Chrome's developer tools and a USB cable (very convenient).

Android and iPhone behave+perform similarly, but not identically. That said, for 90% of use cases, if you improve performance on Android, you'll see the same improvements on iPhone.

Hour for hour, at least for the first pass of profiling, I think you'll get better results on iPhone using chrome+android to profile than using a less rich toolset.

https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging

It'll require Chrome, an Android device able to run the android Chrome app, and a USB cable.

You have to install and use the ADB console command, but once its working, you'll have the full chrome developer tools interface available for debugging mobile.

Comment: This doesn't directly solve the problem, but it is really good advice.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a javascript profiling library (using timers for example) by a bit of searching I've found http://remysharp.com/2007/04/20/performance-profiling-javascript/ but since I didn't test it I can't tell you if its any good. 
You could place timers at various locations in your code and try to track down the bottlenecks that way.

(Js Microtime Library http://phpjs.org/functions/microtime:472)