# Profile javascript on iOS

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, web-applications, webkit

My iPad javascript-based web-app is running rather slowly at times.  Is there any way to profile the javascript code on a iPad?

Comment: check SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384575/profile-mobile-safari-ipad-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The YUI Profiler is a js-only profiler that can grab the stats for you, you can then toss it back to your desktop machine to view it with flash charting:

[YUI Profiler Page at Yahoo Developmer Network](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/profiler/)

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to an Android phone, you can profile your application using desktop Chrome's developer tools and a USB cable (*very* convenient).

Android and iPhone behave+perform similarly, but not identically. That said, for 90% of use cases, if you improve performance on Android, you'll see the same improvements on iPhone.

https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging

It'll require Chrome, an Android device able to run the android Chrome app, and a USB cable.

You have to install and use the ADB console command, but once its working, you'll have the full chrome developer tools interface available for debugging mobile.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a Mac, you can plug your iPad into your computer and choose your iPad from Safari's Develop Menu (you might need to enable it first), and it will allow you to profile JavaScript much like a desktop page.

Comment: Unfortunately when you connect an iPad to the Safari Developer tools you can browse the DOM / CSS etc ... but not profile JavaScript.