# Mysterious severe performance issue on mobile Safari for just one web page

Tags: iphone, responsive-design, mobile-safari

I have a very large (as in feature-rich) responsive website. It consists of over 150 different UI pages, and so far both rendering and performance on mobile are fine (I'm using an iPhone5 to test, and occasionally other devices).

Except for one page, which I am coding now. Here's the temporary dev URL:

http://www.jungledragon.org/apps/jd3/daylight

On Mobile Safari, this page performance extremely poorly:
- It takes several seconds to load, much slower than all other pages
- Once loaded, a touch scroll can take 5-10 secs to do anything
- Mobile Safari as a whole becomes non responding or close to it

I'm trying to troubleshoot the root cause of the issue, but no luck so far. I cannot reproduce this on any desktop browser using a small viewport, not even on desktop Safari. On the desktop, I've inspected several web debuggers to check for any long-running processes, but found none.

Some explanation on what the page does:

1. It will try to detect your current location (using alerts I discovered this takes little time)
2. Based on your current location and the current date, it will calculate the sun times for the day. This too is nearly instant
3. Based on the suntimes, it will dynamically generate a table, and then finally show it on screen

Here's the what I am seeing in detail on mobile Safari:

1. The server response is fine, the page loads quickly and shows the site header soon
2. Next, the content body is blank and stays blank for several seconds (which I cannot explain)
3. Finally, the suntimes table renders.
4. This completes the page, yet as of this point, the page as well as the browser are extremely sluggish, scrolling takes forever, and Safari controls are nearly irresponsive. It looks and feels as if the browser can crash any moment.

Based on my research so far, and given fine performance in all other pages on the site, I'm totally in the dark on what causes this.

**Edit:** Using BrowserStack I did some more tests:

- iPhone 4S: no issues
- iPhone 5S: no issues
- Galaxy SII: no issues
- HTC One X: no issues
- iPhone 5: same issue as above

So I'm not seeing the issue on any desktop browser, and on no mobile device except for the iPhone 5 (iOS7).

**Edit2**: adding more findings and explanation based on comments received:

The issue does not seem animation-related. For this I have a number of proof points. A simple proof point is the page does not do any visual rendering that is much different from any of the other 100+ pages on the site which have no performance issue.

The 2nd proof point can be explained by understanding what is going on in this specific page. What happens is this:

1. The system will detect the current user's time and location. For now assume that the user actually allows location sharing. Using a simple alert, I've been able to proof that location detection is not the bottleneck.
2. Based on the user's time and location, the daylight periods are calculated. This is done by using the Suncalc JS library (https://github.com/mourner/suncalc).
3. The Suncalc library returns an array of daylight periods for the given date and location. I render that array as a table with colored background rows. That is all.

Rendering a table with 12 rows and different background colors is not likely to cause such enormous issues. My theory therefore lies in step 2 being the root cause. The Suncalc library has a lot of advanced math in it. I am thinking (without evidence yet) that either my mobile processor is horrible at those kind of operations, and/or the specific calculation for some reason cause a peak in memory usage (or even a leak).

As an additional proof point: once the page is loaded on mobile, use the right arrow next to the date to navigate to "tomorrow". Again you will see the extremely bad performance. During that step, there is no network activity, no location detection, nothing, just calculations and some very simple rendering. This validates my theory that perhaps the issue lies in the calculation.

Comment: Just FYI, I loaded it in the Chrome app on my Galaxy SIII and noticed the same issue you described. I wonder if it has to do with the JS engine? Chrome uses Blink (a fork of WebKit), not sure what Mobile Safari uses.

Comment: Are you doing more animation here than on your other pages?  Manipulating (via animation) multiple DOM elements typically cripples a mobile device where'd you'd not even notice it on any modern desktop (regardless of resolution).  This would be the first place I'd look, and possible move everything into a requestAnimationFrame.  Even so, you need to be mindful of how many elements are animating either through direct JS or cascaded transforms.

Comment: @CullenJ Thanks for testing that! Please see my updated question for some explanations.

Comment: @MattPileggi Please see my updated question, I believe perhaps it is calculation, not animation, being the issue.

Comment: I ran the page through a profiler and didn't see any heavy calculation load.

Comment: @DavidH.Bennett Interesting. Which profiler setup did you use?

Comment: Based on CullenJ's comment,  I used profiler built into Chrome on a Linux platform, however this might function differently then Mobile Chrome as the underlying geolocation code will be different.

Comment: @DavidH.Bennett Once again, please take note: I'm 100% certain that the issue does not lie in geolocation. I have several proof points for that.

Comment: How are you rendering the table cells for the next and previous day(s)? If they're hidden elements, it could be causing several reflows (which is very bad on performance with a lot of elements.) AFAIK a browser performance hit like that won't show up in a profiler. Just a thought.

Comment: What happens is that based on the results I get back from the suncalc library, I create an HTML string, a single one for all the output. Once the string is done, it is inserted in a single DOM call. While that may not be terribly efficient, I would not expect a simple table to take over 5 seconds to render. You can see it happening each time you click on the "next" and "previous" buttons, the delay.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly,  it looks like native Javascript profilers on that platform are non-existent.  You may also want to try the [Javascript Microtime function](http://phpjs.org/functions/microtime/) referenced [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384575/profile-mobile-safari-ipad-javascript).   You will need to seed your script with calls at points where you think the bottleneck might be.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran this through Chrome remote debugger (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging) on my S3, and it looks like Modernizr's cancelZoom function (showing up in jd3_0006.js) is getting called recursively too many times or by too broad a selector. I've uploaded the profiles into dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kubxk44smm6qqkx/jungledragon_debug..zip

You can import them into Chrome's debugger on the "Profiles" tab.

Comment: Thank you so much, that sounds like a very good clue. I'm having a very busy week but I will look at this as soon as I can. For the record, I'm not consciously calling "cancelZoom" but perhaps something else triggers it.

Comment: Hmmm, don't have an Android device (yet). For now all I can do is research the call to cancelZoom on the web. Actually, I think it is not from Modernizr, it's from this script: https://gist.github.com/zachleat/2008932 That script prevents iOS from zooming the page when entering an input field.

Comment: Gotcha; fair enough. When you have time, see if disabling it (or gutting the file or something) at least speeds it up. Looks like it's a pretty broad selector, so it makes sense.

Comment: I just realized though that I had these performance problems before I even added that script. Disabling it seems to make no meaningful difference.

Comment: That's too bad; I'll do some more poking around when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your performance problem centers around the use of navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() in your runMap() function

```
if (urlDate != null) {
    urlPos(latitude,longitude);
} else {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        $(".img-loading").show(100);
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successPos, errorPos{maximumAge:600000,timeout:10000});
    } else {
        errorPos('');
    }
}
```

Consider using [watchPosition()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/GettingGeographicalLocations/GettingGeographicalLocations.html) instead with a callback which will not halt processing of the script thread.  You can cancel the watchPostion() update by using clearWatch()

Comment: Thanks, but my updated findings (see question edit) rule out that possibility.

Comment: I added a bit about using watchPosition() instead of getCurrentPosition().

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, that really is not the issue. If I alert after getposition, it is almost instant. After that, the performance issue occurs. It is not related to getting the user's location.

Comment: Fair enough,  however,  I am skeptical that the problem is math related per your reference to step 2 in your Edit2.  If this was older iOS (pre 4.3) then maybe but the Nitro (JavaScriptCore) engine performs on par with V8 and others.  My guess is still that it is a synchronous blocking call somewhere, it is almost always the case with these extreme performance disparities .  Hopefully manually profiling will help.    On the plus side,  if you do find a synchronous call, you may be able to use webworkers to get around it.  They available on that platform http://caniuse.com/webworkers

Comment: Thanks. Tonight I'll try to remove location sharing alltogether and hardcode the location, as a test. That should definitely rule out location detection as the issue.

Comment: Let me know what the answer was, I am curious.

Comment: Something came in between, will let you know as soon as I have that test done.

Answer (score 0):

So I've played with this some more, and ran the "Timeline" feature on Chrome (load this file into your chrome timeline tool: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2vpl6z1ntuk3aqj/TimelineRawData-20140328T105820.json), and it looks like this might be your main problem.

Your scripts and libs (including loading Google Maps and jQuery) are getting evaluated AFTER parsing the HTML and running Google Analytics because they are at the bottom of the `body`, not `head`. Unless you have a very good reason to do that, I would recommend moving those to the `head`.

There seems to be a separate problem with scrolling, but perhaps it will be resolved by this change.